# iOS Menu title to navbar title animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, navigation, uinavigationbar

I am trying to achieve a menu translation effect similar to the gif below (from the excellent iOS Sky Guide app), where the large title of the previous menu animates up to become the navigation bar 'back' button.

I am wondering what is the cleanest way to implement such an effect in swift. I've looked through various libraries for anything similar but have drawn a blank.

Can someone put me on the right track? Thanks!

[image: Menu transition]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `UINavigationBar.prefersLargeTitles` property?

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/2908999-preferslargetitles